# RunWithElevatedPrivileges throws error, that the page is not accessible

Tags: runwithelevatedprivileges

I am trying to validate the group at the time of login, have used `runwithelevated` but still I get an error on `"SPGroup managerGroup = Web.Groups["DevTest"];"` That the page is not accessible. How can I get beyond this. If I run the same code once I'm logged in, this runs fine, but I'm trying to validate this at the time of login.

```
 SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()                {
                        using (SPSite CurrentSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
                        { using (SPWeb CurrentWeb = CurrentSite.OpenWeb(web.ID))
                            {SPGroup managerGroup = Web.Groups["DevTest"];
                                bool isManager = CurrentWeb.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup.ID);

                                if (true)
                                {
                                    Response.Redirect("~/sitepages/createrequest.aspx");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Label1.Text = "wrong user id or password";
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
SPGroup managerGroup = CurrentWeb.Groups["DevTest"]; //not Web.Groups
```

Comment: Tried this,but still gets the same error that you do not have access to page

Answer (score 1):

I think the fix is

```
SPGroup managerGroup = CurrentWeb.Groups["DevTest"];
```

//You were using Web object which is out of the elevated context.

Comment: tried this also, but still not working